# jquery post working offline but not working online

Tags: jquery, ajax

The following  code is working good in offline. But after uploading it online, it doesn’t work. Its not sending value to "question_ajax.php" page. Please help me.

```
$.post("ajax/question_ajax.php",
    {
        val:"a"
    },
    function(data,status)
    {
        $("#q_list").html(data);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to take a look at the permissions and change them. When you do "inspect element" with chrome what does the network tab say? Do you get a 200ok or is there an other code visible?

Comment: I am using mozilla. The division "q_list" is blank when checked by "inspect element". And i changed the permission of the file. Changed it many times. But no result.

Comment: Maybe a bit redundant to say but you never know. Did you push the refresh button of your page when inspecting the network tab. When the page is already loaded the network tab will be empty. You need to load it again.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you type out the name of the whole website name instead of only the file name. because it works in offline there is probably a problem with the URL you specified. You could also try `"/ajax/question_ajax.php"` (added a backslash)to see what happens. (if you did not already tried these things). Or use .fail(console.log("did not succeed")) to find get more information where it is going wrong.